How can I apply non-affine transformations to 2D framework elements in WPF?
Historically, WPF is not able to support 2D non-affine transformations out of the box. Typical solutions require setting up a 3D scene. Of course, I'm trying to avoid creating a 3D scene in my application and instead use a package or library to apply non-affine transformations to basic framework elements.
CSS has rotate3d() which pretty much does this for websites. I'd love to know how they engineered that feature, or how I can apply similar transformations to WPF framework elements.
I've spent some time looking into SkiaSharp's SKElement Class but I've been unable to figure out how to apply the transformation to that control's render.
I've also found some of the older threads on this topic of course, but with them being so old I'm hoping there has been some sort of advancements since then that could allow this behavior.
See the below:

Non-Affine image transformations in .NET

Free transform corners of image in C#

Perspective transform with WPF



The problem is that UIElement.RenderTransform requires a Transform which always boils down to an affine matrix. So you couldn't use anything else, including Skia, to put transformed objects in the visual tree and have them still behave like controls. The only thing you could do is use RenderTargetBitmap to create an image of a visual tree fragment, then use Skia to make a new transformed image, and display the image. But any child elements would be "flattened" into the bitmap and no longer active. So this would work only for simple elements.

For what it's worth, WinUI 3 appears to support this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/layout/transforms#3-d-transforms. You might be able to use XAML Islands to get this into your WPF app, though I've never tried that particular flavor of Frankenstein's monster so I can't vouch for it.

Appreciate the advice, Eto. I suspected that a easy solution was unlikely

"Looking" at the examples, I can see taking a half and a half again; skewing the parts; then  putting them together again using writeable bitmaps. After a while, you have a library of "transform" functions.
